# displaying documents in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file

I have a VB.NET form where I want to display the content of a file.
Can you tell which is the best toolbox component for that, please, and if possible, a small example.

I have a solution for this but I don't like how it works:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellMouseClick
    Try
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim selectedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
            Dim i = DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.X
            Dim j = DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.Y
            Dim file_name As String = DataGridView1.Item(i, j).Value.ToString()
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            For Each s As String In File.ReadAllText("D:\Oracle\datastore\" & file_name)
                TextBox2.AppendText(s)
            Next

            'Dim sr As StreamReader = StreamReader("D:\Oracle\datastore\" & file_name)

        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

because it loads row by row and in case of a novel, it will take weeks for complete.

Thank you,

Comment: @AndrewMorton: I replaced the

`For Each s As String In File.ReadAllText("D:\Oracle\datastore\" & file_name)
                TextBox2.AppendText(s)
 Next`

with

`dim sb as new string builder()
sb.append(file.ReadAllText("my_path\myfile))
textbox2.text = sb.tostring()`

but, now, my text looks smaller then before.

I say smaller because I cannot check it as it is displayed artifacts(there are PDFs and DOCXs file)

Is it OK?

Comment: Oh hang on... do you mean that manually clicking all those cells will take a long time?

Comment: yes, I want that when I click on a cell, to load the corresponding file into a text box.